# JsonResult not being called from jQuery function in view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Here is my JsonResult in my controller:

```
//
// GET: /Home/GetTags/

public JsonResult GetTags()
{
    List<string> Tags = Db.Tags.Select(t => t.Name).ToList();

    return Json(Tags, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Here is what the data looks like if I browse to /Home/GetTags:

```
["Author","Movie","Video Game","Website","Republican","Democrat"]
```

Here is the jQuery function in my view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    function split(val) {
        return val.split(/,\s*/);
    }
    function extractLast(term) {
        return split(term).pop();
    }
    $("#Tags")
        // Don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
        .bind("keydown", function(event) {
            if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $(this).data("autocomplete").menu.active) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        })
        .autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetTags")", {
                    term: extractLast(request.term)
                }, response);
            },
            search: function() {
                // Custom minLength
                var term = extractLast(this.value);
                if (term.length < 2) {
                    return false;
                }
            },
            focus: function() {
                // Prevent value inserted on focus
                return false;
            },
            select: function(event, ui) {
                var terms = split(this.value);
                // Remove the current input
                terms.pop();
                // Add the selected item
                terms.push(ui.item.value);
                // Add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                terms.push("");
                this.value = terms.join(", ");
                return false;
            }
        });
});
</script>
```

Copied the jQuery from jQuery UI website. It was working fine with static data. The JsonResult doesn't seem to be called at all. When I put a breakpoint in it and debug it, it never hits the breakpoint.

Comment: what happens when you take out the Allow Get on the JSON return?

Comment: Then when I browse to /Home/GetTags, I get this error: `This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request. To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the "Custom minLength" was the problem (ie the "search" property of the "autocomplete()" function call. Here's the revised jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    function split(val) {
        return val.split(/,\s*/);
    }
    function extractLast(term) {
        return split(term).pop();
    }
    $("#Tags")
        // Don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
        .bind("keydown", function(event) {
            if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $(this).data("autocomplete").menu.active) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        })
        .autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetTags")", {
                    term: extractLast(request.term)
                }, response);
            },
            focus: function() {
                // Prevent value inserted on focus
                return false;
            },
            select: function(event, ui) {
                var terms = split(this.value);
                // Remove the current input
                terms.pop();
                // Add the selected item
                terms.push(ui.item.value);
                // Add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                terms.push("");
                this.value = terms.join(", ");
                return false;
            }
        });
});
</script>
```

Also, I revised the JsonResult in the controller like so, to provide only the values that matched what the user typed in the box:

```
//
// GET: /Home/GetTags/

public ActionResult GetTags(string term)
{
    List<string> Tags = Db.Tags.Select(t => t.Name).Where(n => n.Contains(term)).ToList();

    return Json(Tags, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what about adding the `[HttpGet]` to be above the action.  So, it would be:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetTags()
{
    List<string> Tags = Db.Tags.Select(t => t.Name).ToList();

    return Json(Tags, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: I *think* [HttpGet] is the default behavior, so it's not necessary to specify.